# Aptana 3.0.3 Web Browser Crashes when loading localhost site (repeatable)?

Tags: browser, aptana

I was programming a web site and tried to load it into the embedded web browser within Aptana 3.0.3, but each time I loaded it, the program crashes/closes and give the standard "let Apple know about this". I am running iMac OSX 10.7 (Lion).

---

Tried that... when I do "Check for Updates" I get "No updates found" but with the following error:

No repository found at http://quantum.sourceforge.net/update-site/plugins/.

There doesn't seem to be any kind of page to resolve this issue.

I can't find 3.0.4 anywhere to download either.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

Update to 3.0.4. The issue should be fixed there.

Comment: Tried that... when I do "Check for Updates" I get "No updates found" but with the following error:

No repository found at http://quantum.sourceforge.net/update-site/plugins/.

There doesn't seem to be any kind of page to resolve this issue.

I can't find 3.0.4 anywhere to download either.

Please advise!

Comment: If you do "Help/Check for updates", it should update you to 3.0.4 (just verified). If not, check Available update sites preferences for http://download.aptana.com/studio3-rcp/plugin/update/